# Adding JavaScript to Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

I am not familiar with JS at all and I was wondering how I can get this working in my Magento shop:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3XwZv/3219/)

I apologise in advance if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the jquery library first then add your js code. also the `$` variable is reserved for prototype in magento so you need to add noConflict()

```
<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
 jQuery('#product_pop_before').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow', function(){
        jQuery('#product_pop').fadeIn('slow');
    jQuery('#product_pop').delay(4000).fadeOut(),
        jQuery('#product_pop_before').delay(5000).fadeIn('slow');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I get `$.noConflict is not a function` I added https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js

Comment: @MikeTimTurner did you add before this code or after? my mistake  it is `jQuery.noConflict();`

Comment: This is great. I can only get it to work with an Onload function. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: which function  you want to execute this function?

Comment: Is it possible to run it without a function as I do not want to modify the `<body>` tag

Comment: sorry bro don't get you

Answer (score 0):

Just insert the code in the template you need and wrap it in `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: I've done that and also created a Onload function but when I inspect it shows this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'delay' of null`

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
 jQuery('#product_pop_before').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow', function(){
        jQuery('#product_pop').fadeIn('slow');
    jQuery('#product_pop').delay(4000).fadeOut(),
        jQuery('#product_pop_before').delay(5000).fadeIn('slow');
    });
</script>
```